# javascript, saving reference to nested object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Lets say I have the following object:

```
name = {
    name_one : {
        name_one_A : {
            name_one_A_a : 'John',
            name_one_A_b : 'Kate'
        }
    }
};
```

I could create a reference to 'John' by doing:

```
current_name = name.name_one.name_one_A.name_one_A_a;
```

Lets say I'm referencing "name.name_one.name_one_A" several times, is there a way to create a referencing to this nesting?  This doesn't work, but something like:

```
A = name.name_one.name_one_A;
name = A.name_one_A_b;
```

'name' would then equal 'Kate'.  I know this doesn't work like that, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think `current_name` would be a variable and not a reference. I don't think changing its value would modify a property of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're asking which has caused some confusion among the answers.

If you're referencing `name.name_one.name_one_A` multiple times, you can save that once and then use it:

```
var x = name.name_one.name_one_A;
x.name_one_A_a = 'Bill';
x.name_one_A_b = 'Sue';
```

This works ONLY because the value of `name.name_one.name_one_A` is an object (Object, Array or Function).  So, when you save it to another variable, you aren't actually saving a reference to `name.name_one.name_one_A`, but rather getting the value of that property which is itself an object.  And, when you then modify that object, since `name.name_one.name_one_A` also points to that same object, you will see the value change there too.

---

Javascript does not have the ability to create a reference to a particular property on an object such that you could use only that reference to then change the value of that property.

Using C/C++ terminology, you can't create a pointer to a property on an object in Javascript such that you could change the value in that property using only that pointer.

You would instead have to pass the host object and the property name and you could then change the value of the property on that host object.

---

Or, if the value of the property was itself an object (Object, Array or Function), then you can get the value of the property and then change the object that it points to.

---

So, in your data structure:

```
var name = {
    name_one : {
        name_one_A : {
            name_one_A_a : 'John',
            name_one_A_b : 'Kate'
        }
    }
};
```

There's no way to get a direct reference to:

```
name.name_one.name_one_A.name_one_A_a
```

that would let you modify just the contents of that property at some later time.  Instead, you'd have do something like this where you get a reference to the containing object and use that:

```
var obj = name.name_one.name_one_A;
var prop = "name_one_A_a";

// and then some time later:
obj[prop] = 'Bob';
// or
obj.name_one_A_a = 'Bob';
```

Comment: Asker seems to want a reference to `name.name_one.name_one_A`, not `name.name_one.name_one_A.name_one_A_a`, though, which is possible.

Comment: @itdoesntwork - Hmmm.  I guess it isn't clear what the OP is asking in that regard so I've added info on that to my answer also.

Comment: downvote because it is wrong. You can store a reference to a value in an object hierarchy and modify it, thus modifying the original object.

Comment: @Crowcoder - How do you get a reference to the property that contains `John` and modify the original property through that reference such that the original object sees the new value?  The fact is that you you can't. `John` is not an object itself (it's a string primitive).  There is no way in Javascript to get a reference to a primitive in Javascript and even if you could strings are immutable so you couldn't change it.  This is what the second part of my answer says.  The first part of my answer explains that if the value of a property is an object, you can get a reference to that object.

Comment: @jfriend00 the property that refers to 'John' and the value 'John' are different things. You CAN get a reference to the property and change the original object. I have demonstrated it.

Comment: @Crowcoder - your answer gets a reference to the object containing the desired property and then you use that object and the leaf property name to reference it.  I explain that one can do that in my answer too (the first part of my answer).  Your answer does NOT get a reference to the actual property that can be changed by itself because you can't do that in Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll give your vote back based on the fact that communication is hard and maybe you get what OP intends and I don't regardless of how many times I read the question. Plus the fact that it was accepted answer, and your rep status. But I just don't read the question that way.

Comment: @Crowcoder - well the first sentence of my answer does say it is a bit hard to tell what the OP is asking, but I attempted to cover multiple possible things they might be asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70936/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Scratchpad had an issue with a variable named "name", but this works:

```
var foo = {
'name_one' : {
    'name_one_A' : {
        'name_one_A_a' : 'John',
        'name_one_A_b' : 'Kate'
    }
}
};

var A = foo.name_one.name_one_A;
console.log(A.name_one_A_b);

//yields
```

Kate

> Update:

You can get a reference that is able to change a property value:

```
var foo = {
    'name_one' : {
        'name_one_A' : {
            'name_one_A_a' : 'John',
            'name_one_A_b' : 'Kate'
        }
    }
};

var A = foo.name_one.name_one_A;
console.log(A.name_one_A_b);
A.name_one_A_b = "bob";
console.log(A.name_one_A_b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

Yields:

```
"Kate"
"bob"
"{"name_one":{"name_one_A":{"name_one_A_a":"John","name_one_A_b":"bob"}}}"
```

Comment: I noticed this issue with chrome's dev tools too. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: "name" is in the global scope somehow. Someone smarter than me might know exactly what is going on, but in both FF and Chrome "name" is an object.